# Trying to get 15 year old male into fitness

Tags: workout-routines, workout, exercise-technique, workout-types

I am trying to create a workout plan for a friend. He has absolutely no access to any sort of equipment, and unfortunately lives a couple hundred miles from me, so cannot share mine. He is interested in working out, but knows nothing about it. He has good basic skills, for instance can hold handstands, do pullups, pushups, etc; He also has expressed an interest in trying yoga, after hearing me rave about it. I would like to put together a four week plan for him, using body weight/minimal equipment exercises. I don't know yet what his fitness goals/interests are, and I also don't know if he is at all interested in running.

Edits:
He has only one interest: gymnastics. His only equipment is a 5lb weight. He has no goals, and does not see himself as an athlete at all. It is this lack of motivation, and yet a desire to try that has me a little lost. He is small for his age, no more than 5'5", and rather on the underweight side.

Comment: It's hard to create a plan that caters to him if we don't know his goals. But if you Google for instance [workout routine home](https://www.google.no/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=workout%20routines%20home&oq=workout%20routines%20home&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.2371j0j7) then you will very likely find something that suits him.

Comment: You need to gather more information about his goals, and interests, as every plan is directed towards attainment of certain goals.

Comment: Are you qualified to create such a plan?

Comment: I am unqualified, but have 5 years of workout experience, the input of professionals, and the backing of tireless research. I have created plans for other people, but never for someone so completely naive about what fitness really entails.

Comment: @Hollis - Granted you have worked out a lot, but that does not mean that you are qualified to put together a workout plan for someone that is unmotivated and wants to try a very demanding sport. Point him at a gymnastics school that will train people of his age (Most gymnastics schools I know have limited training for teen+ beginners).

Comment: He doesn't want to become a gymnast. It was the only sport that I could find any spark of interest in at all. He likes watching it, but has no desire to do anything beyond basic floor work. He took lessons for a very short amount of time when he was younger, and as he said 'could do all of it except for cartwheels and the stretchy stuff'. He doesn't want to take lessons again.

Comment: Google - "no weights workouts at home" - there are a ton of exercises for many types of fitness goals.  Keep in mind that Hershel Walker, with he very muscular, shredded build, developed that almost entirely through non-weight workouts.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question on the [Sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) site: [Motivating players to train on their own time](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/motivating-players-to-train-on-their-own-time).  That answer may help you determine an approach.  In your particular situation, I would seize on his interest in gymnastics by explaining how weight training can improve an activity that he appears to like.  But, whatever approach you decide to take, you’ll need to make sure that exercising, for him, is not work.  It should be fun in order to pique his interest.  When he’s ready to make the leap to a formal training program with goals, you’ll need to provide the support he’ll need.  In the end, the decision to partake in a formal exercise program will be his no matter what you may want.